# How to overcome difference bewteen jQuery hide() and jQuery UI hide()

Tags: jquery-ui

I am writing a very simple slideshow and I was using the "regular" hide() like so:

```
jQuery("#featured li:nth-child(1)").hide('slow');
```

This not only hides the li, but it also slowely moves the other li's into position, which is great.

But, now I wanted to use a nicer effect and have changed it to:

```
jQuery("#featured li:nth-child(1)").hide('slide', 'slow');
```

This slides the li out of view with a nice effect, but now the remaining li's no longer move into position with it, but they "wait" until the effect is done and then they suddenly "jump" into place.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different effect like this:

```
$("#featured li:nth-child(1)").hide('fold','slow');
```

I think it depends on your layout because slides goes from right to left so if you have another element below it it will just "pop" in.

Look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F8XcW/

Comment: 'fold' also 'pops'. In fact, I tried all of the effects and they all 'pop' except the default one that comes with jQuery itself (not ui).
I think it is strange that the two work differently.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Ok: http://jsfiddle.net/Yuvalik/dzvru/17/

Code is a bit murky because I copied/pasted from my project and then had to duplicate it in order to show the difference. But as you can see, the blue boxes 'slide' while the red boxes 'pop'.

Comment: I think that the difference is that the 'normal' hide() reduces the width and heigth of the element to 0 (so the other element can 'slide' in) while the UI hide() leaves them unchanged until the end of the animation (so the other elements 'pop' in). Haven't found a solution so far though)

Comment: Ah, you are giving me an idea here. For me it is not important when the other li-s move. It can be either during the effect or after the effect; as long as it doesn't 'pop' so I could probably place a transparent div or span behind the firt li and hide() that after the effect. I'll try and see if that works.